# Can't recover list of items from HTTP POST request

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django app.

In the frontend, I've got a HTML form with some checkboxes that go something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="item1" />Item one<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="item2" />Item two<br/>
```

Upon submitting, the HTTP POST request as seen from the Django backend looks like (let's say I've checked both items):

```
POST:<QueryDict: {u'list': [u'item1', u'item2']}>
```

I'm trying to recover the list:

```
list = request.POST['list']
```

For some reason I only seem to get the last item from the list:

```
['item2']
```

I also tried with

```
 request.POST.get('list', '')
```

with the same result.

Anyone understands what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
list = request.POST.getlist('list')
```

also consider changing the name of variable `list` to something else, it's a built in type.

Comment: That worked, thanks! And, sure, I wasn't really using 'list', that was just for presenting the code snippet.